# Replace Chart Values in Word Document using OpenXML C#

Tags: c#, openxml

I have a Word document that contains two charts. I want to dynamically replace the values in these charts, essentially making them dynamic. I aim to pass values programmatically and update the chart data accordingly. Currently, I'm working with OpenXML in C# to achieve this. Here's an example of the chart structure I'm dealing with:

[Description of the Chart Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPTKW.png)

I need assistance on how to use OpenXML in C# to programmatically update these chart values within the Word document.

Any advice, code samples, or steps on how to accomplish this task with OpenXML and C# would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The image is not needed, we don't care about the outcome - we need code. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - in other words: what have you tried? What is the code that doesn't work and what did you expect, etc

Comment: @riffnl i am just starting working on this i have not write much code yet and doesn't found any helpful document on internet regarding this that's why i didn't post code can you plz give me some idea how its work

Comment: Download the OpenXML Productivity Tool from GitHub. Create a Word document with the Chart you want using Word. Save it. Chart the Chart in the way you want it changed.  Save it as a different file. Use the _Diff_ feature of the Productivity Tool to see what programmatic changes you need.